# How can I trigger an elastic beanstalk scaling event using the aws-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, autoscaling

I'm using the javascript aws-sdk. I have a large file I am about to process and I want to ensure that the normally low number of instances in my beanstalk are boosted up before I begin processing.

How can I trigger a scaling event to guarantee that there are at least 8 instances and wait for that to complete before I begin the next step of my process?

I would accept any non-javascript examples that have analagous api's in the javascript sdk (I can translate it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [updateAutoScalingGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#updateAutoScalingGroup-property) to modify the **minimum number of instances in the Auto Scaling group**. When finished, set the value back to the previous minimum value. The Auto Scaling group will eventually adjust itself to the appropriate level.

Alternatively, you could simply [setDesiredCapacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#setDesiredCapacity-property) to tell Auto Scaling exactly **how many instances** it should have running. However, the scaling policies might then reduce this quantity if there is insufficient work taking place.

In conjuction with setDesiredCapacity, you could call [suspendProcesses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#suspendProcesses-property) to **prevent termination** of instances during your extra-workload period. Then, when you have finished the extra workload, simply [resumeProcesses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#resumeProcesses-property) and the levels will automatically adjust.

Comment: I think `setDesiredCapacity` is what I want becuase it will not be easy to know when its "done" so I will need auto-scaling to scale it back down later.